# fgets outputting weird garbage characters

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, fgets

I'm trying to print a string that `fgets` takes from keyboard input. But when I run the program I get an endless loop of weird characters. Why?

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 6

void stringF();
void revString();
void stringLength();
void verticalString();
void triString();

int main() {
  char string[SIZE];
  stringF(&string[0]);
  system("pause");
  return 0;
}

void stringF(char* str) {
  fgets(str, SIZE, stdin);
  while (str != '\0') {
    putchar(str);
    str++;
  }
}
```

Comment: `str != '\0'` ===> `*str != '\0'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the loop like

```
if ( fgets(str, SIZE, stdin) != NULL )
{

   while ( *str != '\0'){
        putchar(*str);
        str++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, need to check return value for fgets before going into that loop.

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow Ah! thank you, I have been confused on this for a while!

Thanks everyone!